# Openfire configuration to Integrate custom database for MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, openfire

I am trying to setup OpenFire on Ubuntu for MySQL. The issue is i am not able to authenticate users via Database B.

Here is the configuration i need

1) Database A to keep OpenFire tables.
2) Existing Database B containing user inforamation that i need for user login via openfire

Followed openfire guide for custom database integration.
https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html

If anyone having similar configuration able to configure openfire successfully, please help.

Here is the openfire.xml, all the properties mentioned in xml are already saved in ofProp table as well..

```
<jive> 

  <connectionProvider> 
    <className>org.jivesoftware.database.DefaultConnectionProvider</className> 
  </connectionProvider>  

  <database> 
    <defaultProvider> 
      <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>  
      <serverURL>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBOpenFire?rewriteBatchedStatements=true</serverURL>  
      <username encrypted="true">200a0b84b1fa2jsdsdjds31c2abf99393c0a31a1de5c734edf</username>  
      <password encrypted="true">67452fbde9c80636f8486ea43932kksddfdksjdsd0b12284eac45455</password>  
      <testSQL>select 1</testSQL>  
      <testBeforeUse>false</testBeforeUse>  
      <testAfterUse>false</testAfterUse>  
      <minConnections>5</minConnections>  
      <maxConnections>25</maxConnections>  
      <connectionTimeout>1.0</connectionTimeout> 
    </defaultProvider> 
  </database>  
  <setup>true</setup>  

  <provider> 
    <auth> 
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider</className> 
    </auth>
    <user>
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.JDBCUserProvider</className>
    </user>
  </provider> 

  <jdbcProvider>
       <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
       <connectionString>jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBUsers?user=root&amp;password=mypasscode</connectionString>
   </jdbcProvider>

  <jdbcAuthProvider> 
    <passwordSQL>SELECT Password from tblUser where UserName=?</passwordSQL>  
    <passwordType>plain</passwordType> 
  </jdbcAuthProvider>  

  <jdbcUserProvider> 
     <loadUserSQL>SELECT * FROM tblUser where UserName=?</loadUserSQL> 
     <userCountSQL>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUser</userCountSQL>
     <allUsersSQL>SELECT UserName FROM tblUser </allUsersSQL>
     <searchSQL>SELECT UserNameFROM tblUser WHERE</searchSQL>
     <usernameField>UserName</usernameField>
     <nameField>UserName</nameField>
  </jdbcUserProvider> 
</jive>
```

**ofProperty Values:**

```
jdbcAuthProvider.passwordSQL              SELECT UserPassword from tblUser where UserName=?
jdbcAuthProvider.passwordType             plain
jdbcProvider.driver                       com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbcProvider.connectionString             jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBUsers?user=root&password=mypasscode
jdbcUserProvider.loadUserSQL              SELECT * FROM tblUser where UserName=?
jdbcUserProvider.userCountSQL             SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUser
jdbcUserProvider.allUsersSQL              SELECT UserName FROM tblUser
jdbcUserProvider.searchSQL                SELECT UserName FROM tblUser WHERE
jdbcUserProvider.usernameField            UserName
jdbcUserProvider.nameField                UserName
jdbcUserProvider.useConnectionProvider    true
jdbcAuthProvider.useConnectionProvider    true
provider.user.className                   org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.JDBCUserProvider
provider.auth.className                   org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider
admin.authorizedJIDs                      admin@example.com
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with those few informations. Here is what you should do.
1-Check that ubuntu contains the mysql driver to connect.

2-Check the connection to the database B.

> provider.auth.className
>   org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider
>   provider.user.className
>   org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.JDBCUserProvider

3-Create your custom queries for JID, emails, number of JID

4-Create custom queries for databases in case you use non clear passwords.

5-Create custom queries for groups in case you want use external rosters

FYI: insert those queries in the openfire admin server-properties to avoid rebooting the server. If something went wrong, remove that content from OfProperty table of openfire.

Comment: Ubuntu does have mysql driver, and openfire can connect to the database A and login to openfire via Spark.I am having issues configuring openfire to authenticate uses from database B. Both DB's are on the same machine..

Comment: Added the xml to original question. Already added JDBCAuthProvider and JDBCUserProvider in XML as well as ofProperty table.

Comment: what is the result you got with that configuration

Comment: After said configuration, not even able to login to openfire admin panel. Is the configuration ok?

Comment: when you use admin.authorizedJIDs when you use external database for user

Comment: Hi Kassav, can you tell me by example where to user admin.authorizedJID and how to configure it? Are there any issues in openfire.xml i shared?

Comment: just add users to admin.authorizedJID in ofProperty table with jid@domain then reload openfire, then you can access admin console with it

Comment: Updated all the values i have manually inserted in Server Properties in original post. Even after updating the admin.authorizedJIDs key i am still not able to access admin console, Even tried to re-run the setup and reset the admin console password and restarted openfire etc but still no use. Can you please see if the ofProperty values i have set are ok?

Answer (score 0):

Manoj your configuration seems ok and it should work, I also have such configuration and it works fine.

Have you tried to debug the code?

Have you checked the logs to make sure the code is not crashing?

Comment: Hi sohaib, I am testing d connection via spark and openfire admin console so no code is involved/crashing. Can you paste your configuration here plz for XML and ofProp table.

Comment: Manoj, I have same configuration as yours in ofProperty table, however no such configuration in xml, only ofProperty. Beside that, I have custom changes in both Auth Provider and User Provider classes but they are totally business logic specific. If you have in house deployment of Openfire, you need to check the logs first to verify there are no exceptions.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal need your help, is it possible to you to join chat room?

Comment: @Bhavin Yes sure, I have joined the invited room.